# SQL Query with Sum and Group By

Tags: sql, database, group-by, sum

I have a table similar to the example below.

```
Field1 Field2
Chris   100
Chris   200
John    50
Maria   250
John    80
```

I want to achieve the result shown below.

```
Chris 300
John  130
Maria 250
```

I've already achieved this by using 2 separate sql statements. I'm wondering if it can be achieved in a single SQL statement to speed up querying. Thank you very much.

Comment: In what part do you need a COUNT or UNION (as in the title)? That is a SUM only. Maybe add a little more info on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the field you want to sum over and then use sum on the column you want to sum

```
SELECT Field1, SUM(Field2) as Field2
FROM Mytable
GROUP BY Field1
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able with:

```
SELECT field1, SUM(field2) FROM table GROUP BY field1
```

shouldn't it?